# Game sharing not working

Tags: steam, steam-family-sharing

i accidentally activated the key on my other account that i own and so the only person i game share with is myself on the same computer, so no one else could be playing my games. so when i gameshare i go on my main account to play and it shows the game because i have already installed it but it says purchase. however i have been playing that game on my main account for a week now and it has worked perfectly. and now all of a sudden it stopped working. need help thank you.

Comment: Can you tell me what game you want to share, because steam does not allow every game to be shared.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, not all games are shareable. Any game which uses a third party DRM can't be shared across multiple accounts because they connect with the third party DRM which won't allow it to do so.

Second there are several steps involves in game sharing. I'll put them here so that you can check if you have missed them.

1. Login to parent account (From where the game need to be shared)
2. Go to Steam settings -> Family and Click on Authorize this Computer
3. There should be username mentioned in the Eligible account with your child account. (Eg - Gameranand mentioned in screenshot)
4. Check the box below share.
5. Logout of Parent account and Login to Child account.
   [image: Steam setting for Sharing]

Now you should be able to play the game.